# Generic Parameter Search in C++ Projects

Tags: c++, bash, automation, automated-tests

In several C++ projects I needed to tune a parameter like this:

Adapt a constant -> Compile -> Run -> Collect results

What is the best way to automate it? The most primitive version would be to have a bash script. It clones the project's git repository, uses *sed* to change parameters, compiles and runs the application. After it ran all it collects the results.

What is the best way to implement that? Are there good frameworks? Are there better ways to do that?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use command line parameters?

Comment: Yes, instead of the *sed* step one could use command line parameters for *make* to set constants.

Comment: No I mean change constants to variables and set them at the run time. No need to rebuild the project every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not like scripts, maybe you can try some unit test framework, such as [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md), which give you more convenience to run program with different data set,  and many MACRO to test your result.